# Is it possible to have 2 different data sources in grafana dashboard

Tags: grafana

Is it possible to have 2 different sources i.e influxdb and prometheus in a single dashboard in grafana.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, each panel or variable on a dashboard can use different data source.

Variables can use different data source and you can use it on panel no matter what data source uses. It allows you to mix information to have a better dashboard with more details.

Also, you have three especial data sources:

- **Grafana** built-in data source that generates random walk data.
- **Mixed** query multiple data sources in the same panel.
- **Dashboard** use a result set from another panel in the same dashboard.

More info about data sources [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/datasources/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can select the desired data sources in several points of the dashboard configuration (like panels and variables) and you can use different values for each one.

Comment: I added  a variable in the dashboard but the panel I am not able to click to see the graph.